# Not able to view CSV from Python Webscrape

Tags: python

I am new to python and am doing a webscraping tutorial. I am having trouble getting my CSV file in the appropriate folder. Basically, I am not able to view the resulting CSV. Does anyone have a solution regarding this problem?

```
import pandas as pd
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

#Pulling in website source code#

url = 'https://www.espn.com/mlb/history/leaders/_/breakdown/season/year/2022'
page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')

#Pulling in player rows
    ##Identify Player Rows

   players = soup.find_all('tr', attrs= {'class':re.compile('row-player-10-')})
   for players in players:

    ##Pulling stats for each players
        stats = [stat.get_text() for stat in players.findall('td')]
    ##Create a data frame for the single player stats
        temp.df = pd.DataFrame(stats).transpose()
        temp.df = columns
    ##Join single players stats with the overall dataset
        final_dataframe = pd.concat([final_df,temp_df], ignore_index=True)
        print(final_dataframe)

        final_dataframe.to_csv(r'C\Users\19794\OneDrive\Desktop\Coding Projects', index = False, sep =',', encoding='utf-8')
```

Comment: Your dataframe is empty, because in `players = soup.find_all('tr', attrs= {'class':re.compile('row-player-10-')})` you get an empty list. You should also take a look at your variable names: `temp.df` != `temp_df`

Answer (score 0):

I've checked your code.
I've found one issue.
This one.

```
for players in players:

##Pulling stats for each players
    stats = [stat.get_text() for stat in players.findall('td')]
##Create a data frame for the single player stats
    temp.df = pd.DataFrame(stats).transpose()
    temp.df = columns
##Join single players stats with the overall dataset
    final_dataframe = pd.concat([final_df,temp_df], ignore_index=True)
    print(final_dataframe)

    final_dataframe.to_csv(r'C\Users\19794\OneDrive\Desktop\Coding Projects', index = False, sep =',', encoding='utf-8')
```

You have to use this. (players to player, filename with csv)

```
for player in players:

##Pulling stats for each players
    stats = [stat.get_text() for stat in player.findall('td')]
##Create a data frame for the single player stats
    temp.df = pd.DataFrame(stats).transpose()
    temp.df = columns
##Join single players stats with the overall dataset
    final_dataframe = pd.concat([final_df,temp_df], ignore_index=True)
    print(final_dataframe)

    final_dataframe.to_csv(r'C\Users\19794\OneDrive\Desktop\Coding Projects\result.csv', index = False, sep =',', encoding='utf-8')
```

Answer (score 0):

Few issues.

1. As stated in the previous solution, your `for` loop you need to change to `for player in players:` You cant use the same variable as the variable you are looping through
2. You shouldn't use `.` in your variables as you have `temp.df`. That indicates the use of a method. Use underscore instead `_`
3. You never define `final_df`, then try to call it in your `pd.concat()`
4. You never define `columns` and then try to use that (and it would then overwrite your `temp_df` as well). What you are wanting to do is change instead is `temp_df.columns = columns`. But note you need to define `columns`.
5. Your `find_all()` for the `players` is incorrect in that you're searching for a class that contains `row-player-10-`. There is no class with that. It is `row player-10`. Very subtle difference, but it's the difference of returning `None` elements, and 50 elements.
6. `stats = [stat.get_text() for stat in player.findall('td')]` - again needs to be referencing `player` from the `for` loop as mentioned in 1). And in fact, there's a few syntax things in there that we need to change to actually pull out the text. So that should be `[stat.text for stat in player.find_all('td')]`
7. You use `pd.concat` the `temp_df` to a `final_df` within your loop. You can do that (provided you create an initial `final_dataframe` or `final_df` (you use 2 different variable names...not sure which you really wanted), but that will lead to repeating the headers/column names in it and require an extra step. What I would rather do, is store each `temp_df` into a list. Then after it loops through all the players, THEN concat the list of dataframes into a final one.

So here is the full code:

```
import pandas as pd
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

#Pulling in website source code#

url = 'https://www.espn.com/mlb/history/leaders/_/breakdown/season/year/2022'
page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')

#Pulling in player rows
##Identify Player Rows

players = soup.find_all('tr', attrs= {'class':re.compile('.*row player-10-.*')})
columns = soup.find('tr', {'class':'colhead'})
columns = [x.text for x in columns.find_all('td')]

#Initialize a list of dataframes
final_df_list = []

# Loop through the players 
for player in players:

    ##Pulling stats for each players
    stats = [stat.text for stat in player.find_all('td')]
    ##Create a data frame for the single player stats
    temp_df = pd.DataFrame(stats).transpose()
    temp_df.columns = columns
     
    #Put temp_df in a list of dataframes
    final_df_list.append(temp_df)
     
##Join your list of single players stats
final_dataframe = pd.concat(final_df_list, ignore_index=True)
print(final_dataframe)

final_dataframe.to_csv(r'C\Users\19794\OneDrive\Desktop\Coding Projects', index = False, sep =',', encoding='utf-8')
```

**Output:**

```
print(final_dataframe)
                       PLAYER YRS   G   AB   R   H  ...  HR RBI  BB  SO  SB CS    BA
0    1          J.D. Martinez  11  54  211  38  74  ...   8  28  24  55   0  0  .351
1    2       Paul Goldschmidt  11  62  236  47  82  ...  16  56  35  50   3  0  .347
2    3        Xander Bogaerts   9  62  232  39  77  ...   6  31  23  50   3  0  .332
3    4          Rafael Devers   5  63  258  53  85  ...  16  40  18  49   1  0  .329
4    5          Manny Machado  10  63  244  46  80  ...  11  43  29  46   7  1  .328
5    6            Jeff McNeil   4  61  216  30  70  ...   4  32  16  27   2  0  .324
6    7              Ty France   3  63  249  29  79  ...  10  41  18  40   0  0  .317
7    8           Bryce Harper  10  58  225  46  71  ...  15  46  24  48   7  2  .316
8    9         Yordan Alvarez   3  57  205  39  64  ...  17  45  31  38   0  1  .312
9   10            Aaron Judge   6  61  232  53  72  ...  25  49  31  66   4  0  .310
10  11           Jose Ramirez   9  59  222  40  68  ...  16  62  34  19  11  3  .306
11  12      Andrew Benintendi   6  61  226  23  68  ...   2  22  24  37   0  0  .301
12  13       Michael Brantley  13  55  207  23  62  ...   4  21  28  24   1  1  .300
13  14            Trea Turner   7  62  242  32  72  ...   8  47  21  48  13  2  .298
14  15          J.P. Crawford   5  59  216  28  64  ...   5  16  28  37   3  1  .296
15  16         Dansby Swanson   6  64  234  39  69  ...   9  37  23  70   9  2  .295
16  17             Mike Trout  11  57  201  44  59  ...  18  38  30  64   0  0  .294
17                  Josh Bell   6  65  235  33  69  ...   8  39  28  37   0  1  .294
18  19       Santiago Espinal   2  63  219  25  64  ...   5  31  18  40   3  2  .292
19  20           Trey Mancini   5  58  217  25  63  ...   6  25  24  47   0  0  .290
20  21            Austin Hays   4  60  228  33  66  ...   9  37  18  41   1  3  .289
21  22            Eric Hosmer  11  59  222  23  64  ...   4  29  22  38   0  0  .288
22  23        Freddie Freeman  12  62  241  40  69  ...   5  34  32  43   6  0  .286
23  24              C.J. Cron   8  64  249  36  71  ...  14  44  16  74   0  0  .285
24                Tommy Edman   3  63  246  52  70  ...   7  26  26  45  15  2  .285
25  26         Starling Marte  10  54  222  40  63  ...   7  34  10  45   8  5  .284
26  27               Ian Happ   5  61  209  30  59  ...   7  31  34  50   5  1  .282
27  28            Pete Alonso   3  64  239  41  67  ...  18  59  26  56   2  1  .280
28  29    Lourdes Gurriel Jr.   4  58  206  21  57  ...   3  25  15  41   2  1  .277
29  30         Nathaniel Lowe   3  58  217  25  60  ...   8  24  15  57   1  1  .276
30  31           Mookie Betts   8  60  245  53  67  ...  17  40  27  47   6  1  .273
31  32             Jose Abreu   8  59  224  34  61  ...   9  30  33  42   0  0  .272
32               Amed Rosario   5  53  217  31  59  ...   1  16  10  31   7  1  .272
33             Ke'Bryan Hayes   2  57  213  26  58  ...   2  22  26  53   7  3  .272
34  35          Nolan Arenado   9  61  229  28  62  ...  11  41  25  31   0  2  .271
35            George Springer   8  58  218  39  59  ...  12  33  20  51   4  1  .271
36  37       Ryan Mountcastle   2  53  211  28  57  ...  12  35  11  57   2  0  .270
37      Vladimir Guerrero Jr.   3  62  233  34  63  ...  16  39  27  45   0  1  .270
38  39        Cesar Hernandez   9  65  271  37  73  ...   0  16  17  55   2  2  .269
39                Ketel Marte   7  61  223  33  60  ...   4  22  22  45   4  0  .269
40                 Connor Joe   2  60  238  32  64  ...   5  16  32  52   3  2  .269
41  42          Brandon Nimmo   6  57  209  36  56  ...   4  21  27  44   0  1  .268
42             Thairo Estrada   3  59  205  34  55  ...   4  26  14  31   9  1  .268
43  44          Shohei Ohtani   4  63  243  42  64  ...  13  37  24  67   7  5  .263
44  45        Randy Arozarena   3  61  233  30  61  ...   7  31  14  58  12  5  .262
45  46            Nelson Cruz  17  60  222  29  58  ...   7  36  25  50   2  0  .261
46              Hunter Dozier   5  55  203  25  53  ...   6  21  15  50   1  2  .261
47  48            Kyle Tucker   4  58  204  24  53  ...  12  39  31  41  11  1  .260
48                Bo Bichette   3  63  265  35  69  ...  10  33  17  65   4  3  .260
49  50       Charlie Blackmon  11  57  232  29  60  ...  10  33  17  41   2  1  .259

[50 rows x 16 columns]
```

Lastly, tables are a great way to learn how to use BeautifulSoup because of the structure. But do want to throw out there that pandas can parse `<table>` tags for you with less code:

```
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://www.espn.com/mlb/history/leaders/_/breakdown/season/year/2022'
final_dataframe = pd.read_html(url, header=1)[0]
final_dataframe = final_dataframe[final_dataframe['PLAYER'].ne('PLAYER')]
```